# Is there a way to find a browser's user-agent with cmd or python?

Tags: python, selenium, shell, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a code, where I have to use headless browser, but to access a specific website, I need to send user-agent as well. I am currently doing it by sending the following snippet of code(Python/Selenium/ChromeDriver).

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36")
```

But I wanted to make the user-agent genuine, instead of same for every browser/device where the code runs, thus I want to know the user-agent of browser on user's device.

So is there any way to find a browser's user-agent by using Python/Selenium code or command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

httpagentparser extracts os, browser etc... information from http user agent string
so try this

```python
import httpagentparser as agent
s = "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
print(agent.detect(s))
```

Comment: I actually want to know the other way around, I want to know the user-agent of the browser on user's device